# Minizip Libz Apple Mach-O Linker (ld) Error Group

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, linker-errors, unzip

Error on linker.

[image]

I added minizip folder & libz.tbd (Linked Frameworks & Libraries -> libz.tdb)

I didn't get why is this getting errors on the zip extraction code.

Comment: Please share the GitHub link of "MiniZip" library.

Comment: Do you have libz.dylib in your dependencies?

Comment: @JohnTracid ibz.dylib is now found under libz.tbd 
Reference : https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/9176#9176

Comment: @RamkrishnaSharma, I didn't remember this particular link but mostly I downloaded this from original source code. if you have any other reference, please do share with this.

Comment: @NovusMobile please fix your question because you have lib.tbd not libz.tbd.

Comment: @JohnTracid it's due to auto correction !! I changed this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed issue issue with below changes : 
 Target Project -> Basic 
   Apple LLVM 8.1 Language c++

```
//:configuration = Debug
CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = NO

//:configuration = Release
CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC = NO

//:completeSettings = some
CLANG_ENABLE_OBJC_ARC
```

Reason behind this is project => automatic reference counting : change to No. You need to skips those dealloc, release,autorelease iOS sdk 5.0. or less.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't use this lib before, but I think it because this lib is written with C++, and you maybe use this with Objective-C. I fixed similar issue when embedded Objective-C source to a project which is generate by Unity by setting OTHER_LDFLAGS build settings to `-ObjC, -WI, -undefined, -dynamic_lookup` flags (row Target) and OTHER_LDFLAGS build settings to `-ObjC` flag (row Project). Try this and tell me the result.

Comment: @NovusMobile: http://res.cloudinary.com/dwhd61zp4/image/upload/v1494569668/Screen_Shot_2017-05-12_at_12.02.53_PM_ujjxhn.png